# Magento 2: save item options in quote(quote_item_option)

Tags: magento2, quoteitem

I need to add new option for item.

Now in `quote_item_option` i have:

```
{"id":"54","product":"54","selected_configurable_option":"","related_product":"","options":{"4":""},"qty":"1"}
```

But wanna `{"id":"54","product":"54","selected_configurable_option":"","related_product":"","options":{"4":"", "new_option":"some_value"},"qty":"1"}`

I created following controller:

```
<?php

   namespace MySpace\SomeModule\Controller\Quote;
    class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory
         */
        protected $resultJsonFactory;

        /**
         * @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
         */
        protected $checkoutSession;

        /**
         * Update constructor.
         * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
         * @param \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
            \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
            \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession
        ) {
            parent::__construct($context);
            $this->resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;
            $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        }

        /**
         * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json
         */
        public function execute()
        {
            $a = 3;
            $itemId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('item_id');
            $orderNoteEnabledValue = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('new_option');

            if ($itemId && $newOptionValue) {
                $quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote();
                /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $item */
                foreach ($this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getItems() as $item) {
                    if ((int)$item->getItemId() !== $itemId) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $buyRequest = $item->getBuyRequest();

                    $options = $buyRequest->getData('options');
                    if (!$options) {
                        $options = [];
                    }
                    $options['new_option'] = $newOptionValue;
                    $buyRequest->setData('options', $options);

                    $quote->updateItem($itemId, $buyRequest);
                    $quote->save();

                    break;
                }
            }

            return $this->resultJsonFactory->create()->setData(['message' => 'Error']);
        }
    }
```

I debugged, script getts data(option value) successfully, modified it also, but not saving option with new field to table.

What is issue or my mistake?

Thanks for any halp and advise:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution: just need to get option for item_id by name "info_buyRequest".
after unserialize, modify value(add element), serialize and save

Comment: Hello, i am facing the same problem, can you please share the code.

Comment: if you could post your code as an answer that would help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `$item->saveItemOptions()` instead of (or along side with) `$quote->save()`

Answer (score 0):

Add *data* to *data-post* in add to cart button

```
<button class="action tocart primary" data-post="" type="button" <span>Add to Cart</span><button>
```

2 In Product Page set value to Add to Cart form:

```
<div id="some-data">
                <input type="hidden" name="product_some_data" value="some-value" >
            </div>

    <input type="hidden" name="product" value="6">
    <input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="item" value="6">
    <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="47ABLlx5H4AUkcVq">                            <div class="box-tocart">
<div class="fieldset">
            <div class="field qty">
        <label class="label" for="qty"><span>Qty</span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" data-validate="{&quot;required-number&quot;:true,&quot;validate-item-quantity&quot;:{&quot;minAllowed&quot;:1,&quot;maxAllowed&quot;:10000}}">
        </div>
    </div>
            <div class="actions">
        <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action primary tocart" id="product-addtocart-button">
            <span>Add to Cart</span>
        </button>
```